# Average Number of XML Relations

Tags: xml, dtd, nodes

I would like to know if there is any estimation of the Average Number of XML Relations in an average sized DTD File

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such estimation.
Your question is too vague and contains terms that are not common in the XML field. For example what do you mean by "Number of XML Relations"? There is no such thing as average sized DTD, there is no statistic research (at least not one generally available and known in the field) on the existing DTDs to know what would be the average size of a DTD... also, depending on your definition of "XML Relation" it may be no link between the size of a DTD and the number of relations it can define.